# Парсинг заголовка таблицы

Tags: python, re, ascii, parse, prettytable

Необходимо распарсить следующую таблицу:

```
tmp =
['+--------------+-----------------------------------------+',
 '| Something to |        Some header with subheader       |',
 '|  watch or    +-----------------+-----------------------+',
 '|     idk      |      First      |   another text again  |',
 '|              |                 |  with one more line   |',
 '|              |                 +-----------------------+',
 '|              |                 |  and this | how it be |',
 '+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+']
```

Здесь просто чтение (построковое) файла с этой таблицей

Превратить в это: `['Something to watch or idk', 'Some header with subheader First', 'Some header with subheader another text again with one more line and this', 'Some header with subheader another text again with one more line how it be']`

Вот мои попытки это сделать:

```
pluses = [i for i, element in enumerate(tmp) if element[0] == '+']
tmp2 = tmp[pluses[0]:pluses[1]+1].copy()
table_str=''.join(tmp[pluses[0]:pluses[1]+1])
col=[[i for i, symbol in enumerate(line) if symbol == '+' or symbol == '|'] for line in tmp2]

tmp3=[]
strt = ''.join(tmp2.copy())
table_list = [l.strip().replace('\n', '') for l in re.split(r'\+[+-]+', strt) if l.strip()]
for row in table_list:
    joined_row = ['' for _ in range(len(row))]
    for lines in [line for line in row.split('||')]:
        line_part = [i.strip() for i in lines.split('|') if i]
        joined_row = [i + j for i, j in zip(joined_row, line_part)]
        tmp3.append(joined_row)
```

На выходе получается это:

```
tmp3
out[4]:
[['Something to', 'Some header with subheader'],
 ['Something towatch or'],
 ['idk', 'First', 'another text again'],
 ['idk', 'First', 'another text againwith one more line'],
 ['idk'],
 ['', '', 'and this', 'how it be']]
```

Остается только соединить их правильно (и немного подправить) но я не понимаю как!

Есть ещё вариант (идея) с обнаружением границ таблицы:

```
col=[[i for i, symbol in enumerate(line) if symbol == '+' or symbol == '|'] for line in tmp2]
[[0, 15, 57],
 [0, 15, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 45, 57],
 [0, 15, 33, 57]]
```

И далее пробовать как нибудь "по ячейке", но не выходит

Comment: А таблица в каком формате?

Comment: Изначально в текстовом файле, формат [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/)

Comment: Можно посмотреть исходники prettytable

Comment: Кстати документацию смотрели к prettytable, может она из коробки может обратно строки вам отдавать?

Comment: Конечно, смотрел и исходники и документацию. Нет способа вернуть назад таблицу, только если она не создана в ручную

Comment: Можно вашу таблицу в html перевести, а уж обработать html и получить из него данные не составит труда.

Comment: Как перевести текстовую таблицу в html?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134423/discussion-between--and-vovakirdan).

Comment: Мне надо 20 очков что бы говорить в чате… напишите в телеграм? @vovakirdan

Answer (score 1):

Greats to [@hoboman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17842555/hoboman) and [@KarlT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15398259/karlt)

Solution placed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71265798/17845381) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71126003/17845381)

Решение:

```
def parse_table(table, header='', root='', table_len=None):
    # store length of original table
    if not table_len:
        table_len = len(table)

    # end of current "column"
    col = table[0].find('+', 1)
    rows = [
        row for row in range(1, len(table))
            if  table[row].startswith('+')
            and table[row][col] == '+'
    ]
    row = rows[0]

    # split "line" contents into columns
    # end of "line" is either `+` or final `|`
    end = col
    num_cols = table[0].count('+')
    if num_cols != table[1].count('|'):
        end = table[1].rfind('|')
    columns = (line[1:end].split('|') for line in table[1:row])

    # rebuild each column appending to header
    content = [
        ' '.join([header] + [line.strip() for line in lines]).strip()
        for lines in zip(*columns)
    ]

    # is there a table below?
    if row + 2 < len(table):
        header = content[-1]
        # if we are not the last table - we are a header
        if len(rows) > 1:
            header = content.pop()
        # if we are the first table in column - we are the root
        if not root:
            root = header
        next_table = [line[:col + 1] for line in table[row:]]
        content.extend(
            parse_table(
                next_table,
                header=header,
                root=root,
                table_len=table_len
            )
        )

    # is there a table to the right?
    if col + 2 < len(table[0]):
        # find start line of next table
        row = next(
            row for row, line in enumerate(table, start=-1)
                if line[col] == '|'
        )
        next_table = [line[col:] for line in table[row:]]
        # new top-level table - reset root
        if len(next_table) == table_len:
            root = ''
        # next table on same level - reset header
        if len(table) == len(next_table):
            header = root
        content.extend(
            parse_table(
                next_table,
                header=header,
                root=root,
                table_len=table_len
            )
        )

    return content
```

Пример:

```
tmp = [
    '+--------------+-----------------------------------------+',
    '| Something to |        Some header with subheader       |',
    '|  watch or    +-----------------+-----------------------+',
    '|     idk      |      First      |   another text again  |',
    '|              |                 |  with one more line   |',
    '|              |                 +-----------------------+',
    '|              |                 |  and this | how it be |',
    '+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------+'
]
print(parse_table(tmp))
# ['Something to watch or idk', 'Some header with subheader First', 'Some header with subheader another text again with one more line and this', 'Some header with subheader another text again with one more line how it be']
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)